# how can I sort a dict with the order of a list in python

Tags: python, list, sorting, dictionary

for example a is a dict, `a = {1:2,2:3,3:4}`, and `b= [3,1]`

I want to sort `a` to get a tuple list that if keys in `a` is in `b`, sort them in the order of `b`, else put them in the end of the tuple list.

I do it like this :

```
sorted(a.items(), key = lambda (k, v): b.index(k) if k in b else a.keys().index(k))
```

but, I think it is wrong.

so I can I do it using python.

Thanks

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: I think this is fine solution (if it emmits the right answer.. this the else clause maybe wron), a more pythonic way would be using [itertools](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/itertools.html) magic

Comment: Your test data is too narrow your code gives the same results as @mbatchkarov - but if you change the sample data the output changes, they're not the same. ``a = {2:9,9:7,6:5,5:6,1:2,9:8,2:3,4:5,3:4,6:7}``

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
import sys
sorted(a.items(), key = lambda (k, v): b.index(k) if k in b else sys.maxint)
```

For the keys that are not in `b`, we return a very large value, which places them at the end of the sorted result.

Comment: nice take with `sys.maxint`

Answer (score 2):

A good way to handle the special cases is to use tuples as the sort key

```
>>> a = {1: 2, 2: 3, 3: 4}
>>> b= [3, 1]
>>> sorted(a.items(), key=lambda (k,v):(0, b.index(k)) if k in b else (1,))
[(3, 4), (1, 2), (2, 3)]
```

if b is long, it's a good idea to create a dict to speed up the index lookups

```
>>> b_dict = {k:v for v, k in enumerate(b)}
>>> sorted(a.items(), key=lambda (k,v):(k not in b_dict, b_dict.get(k)))
[(3, 4), (1, 2), (2, 3)]
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the expected output that you want, but maybe this helps:

```
a = {1:2,2:3,3:4}
b = [3,1]

r = [(x,a[x]) for x in b if x in a]
```

which gives `r` as a list:

```
[(3, 4), (1, 2)]
```

If this is not the expected output, maybe it helps as an intermediate step.

Comment: I did it like this as the first version, but I not match the need. thanks~

Comment: and I think it may be done in one sentence, but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: I see and I think mbatchkarov's answer is correct then. But it would help if next time you add the expected output to the question, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think this does what you want:

```
a = {1:2,2:3,3:4}
b = [3,1]

print ([(k,a[k]) for k in b if k in a] +
       [(k,a[k]) for k in a if k not in b])
```

Output:

```
[(3, 4), (1, 2), (2, 3)]
```

This would also work:

```
head, tail = [], []
any((head if k in b else tail).append((k,a[k]))
    for k in (b + [k2 for k2 in a if k2 not in b]))
print head+tail
```

I wouldn't call it sorting `a` -- maybe ordering it.